# Is the current Site accessible from a template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-sites

I'm trying to simply get the current `Site` from within a template for parsing like so:

```
<h3>{{ site.name }}</h3>
```

Unfortunately, this isn't bringing anything up.

Is there a way to get access to the current site from a template?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The title of your question presumes that "view" and "template" are interchangeable -- they're not. In order to get the current site in a template, it needs to be added to the context that is used to render the template. If you're using a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), you can write a context processor to do this automatically.

You can write a context processor to do this like so:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

def site_processor(request):
    return { 'site': Site.objects.get_current() }
```

Then, add it to your [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), and use it like so:

```
<h3>{{ site.name }}</h3>
```

Comment: I'm using `django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template`, so I should be covered, right? There isn't a built-in context processor for this?

Comment: Yes, `direct_to_template` uses `RequestContext`, however you'll need to write your own context processor as there isn't one in Django. Alternatively you can pass an argument to `direct_to_template` that adds the current site to the context.

Comment: Why is the function named `site_processor` instead of `site`?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: The function is a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), and that's what the function name implies. It returns a `dict`, and the keys in the dict will be made available as variables when rendering the context. Thus you could change the `site` key to something else, or add additional key/value pairs to the dictionary and access them as well in the template.

Comment: Still the best answer to provide this to a template, but it is worth noting the setting location changed in 1.8: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Consider editing your answer to illustrate how to add a context_procesor to code base and to `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, using the bradleyayers processor gave Null results, so instead of using the Site framework, I used the parameter inside the request.

So the processor will look like that :

```
def host_processor(request):
    return { 'host': request.get_host() }
```

Hope it helped